# NSDate: I enter only utc time components and set the calendar correctly, but the NSDate somehow gets recalculated to my timezone

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I have a date as a string which is in UTC format. I create the NSDate correctly and set the calendar as well to UTC. Nevertheless the date in the end is in local time zone. If my UTC time was 21:25 and I set it up with this code, I in the end get via a NSLog of the new date 23:25. Why?

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setYear:[[timeStamp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)] floatValue]];
[dateComponents setMonth:[[timeStamp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 2)] floatValue]];
[dateComponents setDay:[[timeStamp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8, 2)] floatValue]];
[dateComponents setHour:[[timeStamp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(11, 2)] floatValue]];
[dateComponents setMinute:[[timeStamp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(14, 2)] floatValue]];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]  initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *configuredDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

BTW: I am in timezone Berlin. So +2 would be correct, but still, the date should be in UTC?!

Here is the edit:

2018-10-17 19:11:54.964754+0200 FollowMe[2005:91382] Time stamp before: 2018-10-17T17:37Z

2018-10-17 19:11:54.965017+0200 FollowMe[2005:91382] Configured date: Wed Oct 17 19:37:00 2018

2018-10-17 19:11:54.965096+0200 FollowMe[2005:91382] Time Interval: 1539797820.000000

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example input string and the value of `configuredDate.timeIntervalSince1970` for that input string.

Comment: Why are you parsing the original string this way? Use an `NSDateFormatter` to parse the original string. It is so much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to set the defaultTimezone to "UTC" before creating the calendar, and then create the date using dateFromComponents. 
Now the date is correctly created, and can be retrieved and converted to whatever timezone needed using a dateFormatter, for which the desired timezone is set.

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setYear:1987];
[components setMonth:4];
[components setDay:10];
[components setHour:0];
[components setMinute:0];
[components setSecond:0];
[components setNanosecond:0];

NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *date = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:components]; 
NSLog(@"%@", date); // puts out Fri Apr 10 00:00:00 1987

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.s ZZZZ"];

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Berlin"]];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]); // puts out 1987-04-10 00:00:00.0 GMT+02:00
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]); // puts out 1987-04-09 22:00:00.0 GMT
```

Now if I change defaultTimeZone:

```
NSTimeZone *UTCzone=[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone= UTCzone;
```

and then re-create a calendar, and a date (from the same components):

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar2 = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *date2 = [gregorianCalendar2 dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"%@", date2); // puts out Fri Apr 10 02:00:00 1987    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Berlin"]];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date2]); // puts out 1987-04-10 02:00:00.0 GMT+02:00
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date2]); // puts out 1987-04-10 00:00:00.0 GMT
```

It was frustrating because I could find no mention in the Xcode documentation that NSDate is always created with the default timezone. Of course I tried using what the documentation says [(https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000185-BBCBDGID)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000185-BBCBDGID),

```
[gregorianCalendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```

that just didn't work... Can't figure out for the life of me why not. If anybody knows, please share.

Comment: STOP - dunno what I did other than clean my Xcode build folder a few times... but now setting of the timezone works as in MichiZH's code, there's no need to change the default time zone. I also discovered that if I set the [component setTimeZone] to GMT, which is an option for iOS, I have to explicitly set the same one in [calendar setTimeZone]. Otherwise the calendar timeZone defaults to the local timezone, and the resulting date fails the [d isValidCalendar] check - as component TZ and calendar TZ now don't match. If I hadn't validated, I'd never have known as no errors during date creation.